# Is there a better way to map all but the first item?

Tags: clojure

I feel like there must be a cleaner way to do this, but I don't see it.

```
(defn map-rest
  "Passes through the first item in coll intact. Maps the rest with f."
  [f coll]
  (concat (list (first coll)) (map f (rest coll))))
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Destructuring and using `cons` instead of `concat`:

```
(defn map-rest [f [fst & rst]] (cons fst (map f rst)))
```

REPL output:

```
user=> (map-rest inc [1 2 3 4 5])
(1 3 4 5 6)
```

Comment: Talk about losing sight of first principles! Thanks.